Firebase token to access google calendar api from custom backend
I'm not sure if I can do this but here is my problem. I have a mobile application that needs to sync some data to my custom backend. I use Firebase auth to authenticate the users with the Google SignIn provider. Now what I want to do is use my custom backend to add some events to the calendar on behalf of the user. How can I do that without asking every time for the users permission? Is it even possible?
I know I can add the scopes on my google sign provider and use that token to add some events to google calendar but from my research that token expires in 1 hour. I would prefer not having to ask so often for permissions from my users

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I kinda had the same problem. In short, it's possible, but you should implement the server-side flow.
That way, besides the access token, you will have a refresh token too.
From my understanding, you only use the client side flow with Firebase (which is session based). You could pass the access token to the cloud function, but that's a security risk you should not take.
